# display new message to new user App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I'm using Google App engine to allow a user to log in to the site. Once they log in, I create a token for them and use this to check whether the user is logged in. I want to be able to display a different message to first time users and a different one for returning users.

```
        {% ifequal cookie None %} 


<a  href="https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=X&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/">Log In</a>

            <hr></hr>  
        {% else %} 

                        {% for user in set %}
                            {% ifequal user.session_ID access_token %}
                                <a  href="/logout">Logout {{user.user_name}}</a>
                                    <hr></hr>  
                            {% else %}
                            {%endifequal%}
                        {% endfor %}

   <h3 align="center"> 





        {% endifequal %}
```

Currently, there are only two choices: signed in and not.

Comment: Do you mean a first time user or just a user without an active session cookie?  The former would require some sort of logging on your part (ie a user profile entity that keeps a record of users that have signed in to you app in the past).

Comment: @Kevin the login process is a 2 step process. Once the user has authenticated with the second system, a user profile is generated for them in the database. I want some way of checking if the user is in the database already, if they are they do not need to go thru the second OAuth process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your user profile entity looks something like this:

```
class UserProfile(db.Model):
    UserID = db.UserProperty()
    FirstSession = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Try this:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

user = users.get_current_user()

is_existing_user = UserProfile.all().filter('UserID = ', user).get()

if is_existing_user:
    #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in the template? I tried the following:
`check = db.Query(User)
        check = check.filter("foursq_auth_token = ", access_Token)
        results = check.fetch(limit=1)
        if len(results) > 0:
            doRender(self, "index.html", {"logged_in":"yes"})`

But this doesn't seem to work :-(

Comment: @User082074 You shouldn't be trying to do this in the template - that's not what it's for. Do it in your code, and do the check for 'is_existing_user' in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a boolean variable in the user class for this case:

```
is_first_time_user = db.BooleanProperty(default=True,verbose_name="is First Time User")
```

or a function in the user class that the template tag can use.